# Redrawing GTK from function

Tags: c, gtk

I have a function that uses:

```
  g_signal_connect (area, "expose-event", G_CALLBACK (cb_expose), data);
  gtk_widget_show_all (main_window);
  gtk_main();
```

where I am passing parameters with data. The cb_expose function uses the data to draw graphics on the canvas.

After this function, I'd like to change the variable data and redraw the canvas with the updated data. How would I do this?

Thought of having some parameter in the function that would raise a flag for redrawing. But not sure how to approach this.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you need to add a line like this one:

gdk_window_invalidate_rect(widget->main_window, &widget->allocation, FALSE);

before the return of your cb_expose() function. This function forces the rect to be redrawn right now, not later. If you're using double-buffering, you'll have to swap buffers, too.

See https://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-invalidate-rect